# Client to Server Remote Function Calls in Python. How to implement?

Tags: python, twisted, xml-rpc

I'm trying to set up a simple client to server interface for calling functions/programs on the server.  A client will send a simple command to the server listening for such commands. Once the server receives a command from the client it will execute the following function or program on the server. I have looked into a simple TCP server receiving a text string and parsing that string then executing the a function or external program.  I have read into using XML-RPC implemented with a twisted server as well.

What I'm asking is which would be the easiest to set up or are there any other ways to easily do this task?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great tutorial for twisted that will do just fine as a teaching tool (and guide you by hand in writing a basic server/client services). Have a go at it http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/tutorial/ what you will probably want to do is parse received info and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If it is appliable in your case, maybe you can use full-featured system for async/remote job execution like [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one way to achieve your requirement ach with some pros and cons:

- Python Low Level Sockets

Using Standard python socket libraries and cliet server architecture

- Connecting to Server via protocols like Telnet/SSh and then triggering some code.

Using Python libraries like Telnet/ssh or Subprocess.

- XML-RPC

Sending a XMP RPC request as described here http://docs.python.org/2/library/xmlrpclib.html

In my opinion easiest method to achieve remote method triggering is via Python Subprocess Module. I generally use following kind of syntax for my general purposes.

```
import subprocess

ret = subprocess.call(["ssh", "user@host", "program"]);

# or, with stderr:
prog = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "user@host", "program"], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
errdata = prog.communicate()[1]
```

Hope it helps